# Playing music from the iPhone wirelessly to a stereo that doesn't support Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, hardware-recommendation, streaming

I'm looking for a way to stream music from my iPhone to a stereo which doesn't support Bluetooth, but does support connecting a standard audio cable to it. For example, I can take a standard audio cable and connect my iPhone directly to this stereo. However, I'm looking for a solution that will free me of wires on the iPhone side.

If there was some kind of Bluetooth device which has a standard audio cable as its output and as its input it uses a Bluetooth profile that the iPhone supports for wireless audio listening, I guess that would work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Damned! The links of the 2 answers are already broken :-/ Internet is a moving thing...

Comment: ALso look at Airport Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the [Sony DRC-BT30](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00385XUE2). It works really well and does exactly what I need it to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Sony Ericsson MBR-100](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/accessories/overview/mbr-100) is a bluetooth adapter that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been very pleased with my [Belkin wall powered bluetooth receiver](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=508754). It works well even with microwave oven and lots of other bluetooth in a house with chicken wire / plaster walls. (i.e. a disaster for 2.4 GHz radio)