# Mac Mini as a bluetooth headset?

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth

Is it possible to have a Mac Mini running OSX act as a bluetooth headset for the iPhone? (sound comes out the mini's speakers, sound goes in the mini's mic)

I'm guessing that the mini would have to support the bluetooth [headset profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29)?

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/transmitting-audio-from-iphone-to-mac-via-bluetooth-a2dp-profile

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Belkin Bluetooth](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2430LL/A/Belkin-Wireless-Bluetooth-Music-Receiver) receiver to stream music to the speakers connected to my older Core Duo mini with the free [LineIn](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) by Rogue Amoeba. I've not worked out getting microphone input to the iPhone but am guessing it's might not be possible.

Comment: I'm not able to pair my white plastic topped Mini (Core Duo) with a headset to accomplish microphone input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://www.airserverapp.com/ . It basically turns you mac into and AirPlay device for Video, Audio and Pictures. It will not use bluetooth, but your local network which has it's benefits, (range mostly).

Comment: I'm looking for more headset functionality. The headset profile has ring notification and caller ID information.