# Send audio from my laptop to my iPhone over Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I have an iPhone 4, and Philips dock speakers which I use with the phone.

The dock doesn't have any aux input, and I would like to use the dock as a speaker for my laptop.

I know I can achieve it through Wi-Fi, but my laptop doesn't have one. Is there any Bluetooth alternative to send laptop audio to my iPhone?

Comment: as a point of curiosity how does your laptop have bluetooth but not wifi?

Comment: It does have both of them, but the wifi card stopped functioning, and the laptop is quite old so not keen on getting it repaired.

Answer (score 1):

**According to your comment, you would be happy with a Ubuntu solution where WiFi works.** Therefore, follow this thread at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71769/how-to-broadcast-audio-output-to-iphone).

What they basically suggest, is:

> 1. Create a webserver with IceCast under Ubuntu und stream your audio from there (Here is a [Howto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network/28498#28498))
> 2. Connect your iPhone via an [IceCast compatible app](http://icast.anthonymyatt.net/).
> 3. Now you can connect your iPhone to your IceCast server and stream audio

If this doesn't work for you because of complexity, follow the lead of:

> 1. **creating your own local streaming server on Ubuntu**, or just create a "normal server"
> 2. and then **access the files from there on your iPhone with a app** which
>      can connect to that server.

---

A Bluetooth solution for a Windows environment [is over here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/connect-iphone-or-ipod-windows-7-bluetooth/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/can-i-transmit-audio-from-iphone-to-mac-via-a-bluetooth-a2dp-profile) from another user. Someone else recommended [AirFoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/). I've never used any of these products, but check em out. Report back if anything suits your needs

Comment: Unfortunately my windows 8 drivers don't support wifi that is why I'm looking for a bluetooth solution. If a software is available which can stream music from Ubuntu(Wifi works there! ) then it is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind removing your iPhone from the dock when you want to play audio from your laptop, there is a hardware solution: numerous [30-pin Bluetooth receivers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=30%20pin%20bluetooth%20receiver&ia=products) are available which plug into a dock in place of the iPhone or iPod.